constrained optimization and active constraints at solution: statistical measures
Suppose we want to minimize an objective function (fitting parameters of a PDE) and the parameters have box constraints and linear inequality constraints. Some of the constraints are active at the solution.
In unconstrained optimization, I often see quantitites such as the confidence interval, correlation matrix or the concept of local identifiability
What statistics can be done in the constrained case?
Also references are appreciated.

I have to admit that I don't see the connection between optimization and statistical quantities. Can you be more explicit about this?

@WolfgangBangerth There may not be a direct connection. My question is more of the kind: When we have identified parameters, what can we say about the reliability of those parameters, e.g. a confidence interval? Something of this kind is usually what people do after having identified parameters. But clearly, a confidence interval does not really make much sense if constraints are active at the solution point.

I have to admit that I do not have a proper reference on this topic. I have the book from Nocedal and Wright, but is does not cover the "postprocessing" of optimization.

Ah, so you're asking a question of the form "Given that the inputs of the problem are stochastic, the optimal solution will also be stochastic. What can we say about the distribution of these stochastic outputs (the solution)?"

@WolfgangBangerth Yes, exactly.

Then I don't see why constraints make that any different. The constraint is typically not of the form "minimize f(x) such that x=42", which of course leaves no room for optimization, but "minimize f(x) such that g(x)=0" which in high-dimensional spaces leaves much room to find a minimum.

That is true that there is enough room for finding a minimum. But imagine we miminize f(x1,x2) such that x1>=0 and x2>=0. The solution is x1' =  x2' = 0. Then, it does not make sense to say x1 = x1' +- 0.5 or x2 = x2' +- 0.5 because x is bouded. Similarly, a correlation matrix is not really appropriate given the active constraints at the solution. Correct me if I am wrong.

Well, no, of course not. You cannot use simply error-propagation methods that only track $\pm \sigma$.

That is kind of my question: What can I do instead?

Track the probability distribution of the solution. This is called Uncertainty Quantification (UQ).

Can you point me to a paper or text book?

I have none at hand right now, but there are several books on UQ.
